# how to use python dictReader for multiple delimeter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

i have CSV file like this

```
slNo,quatinty,data1,data2,data2
1|2|3|sssa|QQ
1|2|3|sssa|QQ
1|2|3|sssa|QQ
1|2|3|sssa|QQ
1|2|3|sssa|QQ
```

first row is comma separated delimiter, All other rows are '|' separated.
i used python dict reader for this. is there is any i can use dict reader with this file

```
reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['slNo','quatinty','data1','data2','data2']

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    # you can read fieldnames from the file if you want
    # fieldnames = next(f).strip().split(',')
    
    rdr = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter='|')
    next(rdr) # skip the header, if fieldnames were hardcoded
    for line in rdr:
        print(line)
```

output

```
OrderedDict([('slNo', '1'), ('quatinty', '2'), ('data1', '3'), ('data2', 'QQ')])
OrderedDict([('slNo', '1'), ('quatinty', '2'), ('data1', '3'), ('data2', 'QQ')])
OrderedDict([('slNo', '1'), ('quatinty', '2'), ('data1', '3'), ('data2', 'QQ')])
OrderedDict([('slNo', '1'), ('quatinty', '2'), ('data1', '3'), ('data2', 'QQ')])
OrderedDict([('slNo', '1'), ('quatinty', '2'), ('data1', '3'), ('data2', 'QQ')])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` for this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('FILE.csv', skiprows=1, delimiter='|', header=None)

with open('FILE.csv') as f:
  df.columns = f.read().strip().split("\n")[0].split(",")

print(df)
```

Here is my output:

```
   slNo  quatinty  data1 data2 data2
0     1         2      3  sssa    QQ
1     1         2      3  sssa    QQ
2     1         2      3  sssa    QQ
3     1         2      3  sssa    QQ
4     1         2      3  sssa    QQ
```

To get a dictionary use `df.to_dict()`:

```
print(df.to_dict())
```

Output:

```
{'slNo': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1}, 'quatinty': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2}, 'data1': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3}, 'data2': {0: 'QQ', 1: 'QQ', 2: 'QQ', 3: 'QQ', 4: 'QQ'}}
```

Working with a Pandas Dataframe is way easier.